# Obtaining navigation button controls in calabash-ios v0.9.169

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

Prior to calabash-ios v0.9.169 I used to be able to obtain certain navigation button controls using the following query:

```
query("view:'_UIToolbarUINavigationButton'")
```

Since v0.9.169 I can no longer obtain this control- the query returns an empty array. I can do a more general query for UIButton and it is returned in the result:

```
[2] "<_UIToolbarNavigationButton: 0xd9ab880; frame = (-11 7; 41 30); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd9aba50>>",
```

What is the recommended way to obtain this button?

---

System info:

- xcode-select --print-path -> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
- xcodebuild -version -> Xcode 5.1.1 Build version 5B1008
- calabash-ios version -> 0.9.169
- calabash.framework version -> 0.9.169
- server_version['version'] -> "0.9.169"

Comment: Yep- my bad- this was a typo as a result of find & replace rename of all the queries to prefix controls with UI (something that changed @v0.9.169). Thanks Joshua!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `query("view:'_UIToolbarUINavigationButton'")`

There is a typo in your query.

`_UIToolbarNavigationButton'`

not

`_UIToolbarUINavigationButton`

I will take this opportunity to point you to some alternative and more stable ways of interacting with Toolbar Buttons:

- [wait_tap](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/blob/master/changelog/0.9.169.md#experimental-synchronous-operation-combining-waiting-waiting-for-animations-and-tapping)
- [briar gem's navbar.rb](https://github.com/jmoody/briar/blob/master/lib/briar/bars/navbar.rb)

Comment: Thanks for the info Joshua- and for spotting my typo! I've reviewed wait_tap and not sure how that helps me in this scenario? Will briar ever be merged into calabash- I'd prefer less moving parts in my environment setup.

Comment: Briar is the proving ground for calabash features.  It will probably never be fully merged.  wait_tap is wait + tap rolled into one function.  Navigation buttons are often visible to `query` before they can actually be touched because of animations.